# How does Android Marshmallow libsqlite.so use ftruncate64 when the source calls ftruncate?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-6.0-marshmallow, virtualfilesystem

Our Android software uses a virtual file system (VFS) for SQLite, which has been working correctly.  Once we began using it with Android 6 (Marshmallow) all sorts of weird errors started to occur with large negative offsets being passed to ftruncate(), stack overflows, data corruptions, etc.  Using `readelf` (among other tools), we eventually traced the problem to a change in the imports used by `libsqlite.so`:  Lollipop and earlier import `ftruncate` and `mmap`, the newest libraries import `ftruncate64` and `mmap64`.  We "solved" the problem by changing which functions we use depending on the API version (Marshmallow is version 23):

```
/*
 * Empirical testing of Tab S2 running Marshmallow revealed the SQLite
 * unix_syscall table uses "ftruncate" and "mmap" as connection points,
 * but the actual functions linked against are the *64 versions.  This
 * leads to stack corruption and all sorts of nasty errors as a result.
 */
if (getApiVersion() >= 23)  // for Marshmallow
{   setUnixSystemCall(NULL, "ftruncate", our_ftruncate64);
    setUnixSystemCall(NULL, "mmap", our_mmap64);
}
else                        // for Lollipop & older
{   setUnixSystemCall(NULL, "ftruncate", our_ftruncate);
    setUnixSystemCall(NULL, "mmap", our_mmap);
}
```

Looking at the source code both from http://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-amalgamation-3081002.zip and https://github.com/android/platform_external_sqlite/blob/master/dist/sqlite3.c all that the `C` source calls is `ftruncate` and `mmap` which makes our methodology "questionable" at best.

How does `libsqlite.so` import and use `ftruncate64` and `mmap64` where the source code only calls `ftruncate` and `mmap`?  Are we not looking at the correct source code repository?  Is there something going on at a link step?  Did Marshmallow remove support for the non-64 bit versions of these functions?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the headers in the NDK don't exactly match the corresponding headers that the OS is ​built with!

Bionic:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/marshmallow-release/libc/include

Here's the way to BUILD the NDK:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/marshmallow-release

In particular,

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/marshmallow-release/libc/include/unistd.h

```
#if defined(__USE_FILE_OFFSET64)
extern int truncate(const char *, off_t) __RENAME(truncate64);
extern off_t lseek(int, off_t, int) __RENAME(lseek64);
extern ssize_t pread(int, void *, size_t, off_t) __RENAME(pread64);
extern ssize_t pwrite(int, const void *, size_t, off_t) __RENAME(pwrite64);
extern int ftruncate(int, off_t) __RENAME(ftruncate64);
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/marshmallow-release/libc/include/sys/mman.h has similar macros for `mmap` - the `__RENAME()` *in the system headers* means that any code built using the system headers (e.g., `libc.so`) will only export `ftruncate64`, not `ftruncate`, and when an app that calls `ftruncate` is linked against `libc.so`, it instead imports `ftruncate64` rather than the call the source code was written with.

We didn't dive into the `__RENAME()` macro to investigate how this magic happens - the reality of trying to get a product out the door prohibits how deep we can go down the rabbit hole.  If anybody wants to investigate this further, however, this is where you start.